# Can I access function's children inside from parent via React.Children.toArray?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, children, react-hooks

Can I access function's children inside from parent via `React.Children.toArray`?

Here is a `Parent` function that counts children. In a real world example, it should have done something with the children.

```
function Parent({ children }) {
  // Flat children.
  function flatChildren(arr, initial) {
    return arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
      if (React.isValidElement(current) && current.props.children) {
        return flatChildren(React.Children.toArray(current.props.children), [
          ...accumulator,
          current
        ]);
      }
      return [...accumulator, current];
    }, initial || []);
  }

  const flat = flatChildren(React.Children.toArray(children));
  return <div>Length: {flat.length}</div>;
}
```

And here is a `Child` function:

```
function Child() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>test</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now if I render the `Parent` with the function or with plain React Elements, it does not work the same:

```
<>

  <Parent>
    <div>
      <span>test</span>
    </div>
  </Parent>

  <Parent>
    <Child />
  </Parent>

</>
```

The first displays "Length: 3" and the second displays "Length: 1".

I can understand why: React did not execute the function: it's a black box. Still, the component *is* rendered, so there must be a way to map the actual rendered children. Is it possible?

Side note: I actually call `useEffet` in my `Parent` for parsing children, so maybe I can do something here.

Comment: If the children you want to count are dom elements, you can manage to do so with refs in runtime. If you want to count components, I don't think it's possible. 
With refs, you can use regular dom functions to go through children.